# Python Function to Incorporate Data Transform

Tags: python, data

I am new to python and I have developed a model and like to create a function for API use.

For example: predict(1,2,1) <-- call the function

if the first argument is 1 and it has 7 categories, the first 7 data input would be (1,0,0,0,0,0,0) If the second argument is 2 and it has 5 categories, the input includes the first 7 is (1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0) If the third argument is 1 and it has 3 categories, the input includes the first and second is (1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0)

How do I write that in a python function for api use? Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle

# load model
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))

def predict(Project_Sector, IncidentType, Parent_Child_Type):

    features = ['Project_Sector', 'IncidentType', 'Parent_Child_Type',]

    s = predict("Project_Sector", "IncidentType", "Parent_Child_Type")

    data_transf = pd.get_dummies(s,columns=features)

    # predictions
    result = model.predict(data_transf)

    # send back to browser
    output = {'results': int(result[0])}

    # return data
    return jsonify(results=output)
```

Comment: Hi Cassie, welcome to the site. I'm not sure wether I completely understand your question. Perhaps you could include a sample request and expected response.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I've provided some example in the post. Thanks!